# How to solve tkinter entrywidget data transfer to textwidget

Tags: python, tkinter

the program code is presented below but i don't understand how to transfer entrywidget data  from entrywidget to textwidget i need to create Add BUTTON to transferring entrywidget data.

the code is

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import*

def update_sum(first_number_tk, second_number_tk, sum_tk) :
# Sets the sum of values of e1 and e2 as val of e3
   try:
    sum_tk.set((float(first_number_tk.get().replace(' ', '')) + float(second_number_tk.get().replace(' ', ''))))
   except :
    pass

   root.after(10, update_sum, first_number_tk, second_number_tk, sum_tk) # reschedule the event
   return


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1000x600')

e1_tk = tk.StringVar(root) # Initializes a text variable of tk to use to get e1's val.
e2_tk = tk.StringVar(root) # Initializes a text variable of tk to use to get e2's val.
sum_tk = tk.StringVar(root) # Initializes a text variable of tk to use to set e3's val.

# Entries
e1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = e1_tk)
e1.grid(row=1,column=1)
e2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = e2_tk)
e2.grid(row=1,column=2)
e3 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = sum_tk)
e3.grid(row=1,column=3)

e4=tk.Label(root,text="SL")
e4.grid(row=1,column=0)

e3_tk = tk.StringVar(root) # Initializes a text variable of tk to use to get e1's val.
e4_tk = tk.StringVar(root) # Initializes a text variable of tk to use to get e2's val.
sum2_tk = tk.StringVar(root) # Initializes a text variable of tk to use to set e3's val.


# Entries
e5 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = e3_tk)
e5.grid(row=2,column=1)
e6 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = e4_tk)
e6.grid(row=2,column=2)
e7 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = sum2_tk)
e7.grid(row=2,column=3)

e8=tk.Label(root,text="DR")
e8.grid(row=2,column=0)

mytext=Text(root,bg="white",width=30,height=20)
mytext.grid(row=10,column=20)
mytext.insert('1.0', '       my status here\n')
mytext.insert('2.0', '       my status here\n')
mytext.insert('3.0', 'Item    num1    num2    total\n')

# Will update the sum every second 10 ms = 0.01 second it takes ms as arg.
root.after(10, update_sum, e1_tk, e2_tk, sum_tk)
root.after(10, update_sum, e3_tk, e4_tk, sum2_tk)

root.mainloop()
```

**I hope you will solve this problem.. Thanks in advance..**

Comment: You should _not_ catch the exception. It is probably telling you why your code isn't working.